# Who is the owner of a concatenated string once its owner goes out of scope?

Tags: string, rust, ownership

I am learning Rust and [chapter 8.2 of the Rust Programming Language book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.51.0/book/ch08-02-strings.html#appending-to-a-string-with-push_str-and-push) raised some doubts:

> ```rust
> let mut s1 = String::from("foo");
> let s2 = "bar";
> s1.push_str(s2);
> println!("s2 is {}", s2);
> ```
>
> If the `push_str` method took ownership of `s2`, we wouldn’t be able to print its value on the last line.

I understand this and the fact that the concatenation adds only the reference to the string and does not get its ownership. This should mean that if `s2` goes out of scope or is changed, the concatenated string should be deallocated or changed but it is not happening:

```rust
let mut s1 = String::from("foo");
{
    let mut s2 = String::from("bar");
    s1.push_str(&s2[..]);
    println!("s2 is {}", s2);

    println!("s1 is {}", s1);
    s2 = String::from("lol");

    println!("s2 is {}", s2);
}
println!("Value after change is {}", s1);
```

Since the concatenated string is only a reference to the string `s2` and `s1` does not get the ownership of the string, once `s2` goes out of scope, who is the owner of the concatenated string?

Comment: The concatenated string is simply `s1`, which is declared as mutable and is indeed mutated by the `push_str` method.

Comment: *"the concatenated string is only a reference to the string s2"* What do you mean here ? `s1.push_str(&s2[..]);` copies the bytes of `&s2[..]` to the buffer of `s1`.

Comment: Rust's strings are stored in a contiguous array of bytes, so `push_str` has no choice but to copy. Even if it took ownership of its argument, it'd still have to copy, the only difference would be that the memory of the other string would be freed at the same time.

Comment: I mean that when you are using the `&` the variable is just borrowing the allocated memory, is not copying it or taking its ownership, am I wrong? Maybe I have been just confused from the chapter since it does not mention that the `push_str` is copying the `&str` to the `String` value

Comment: @BogdanPop You are correct that mere *passing* of a reference is not copying underlying data. But what the function you call will *do* with that reference is another matter entirely. `push_str()` will append (copy) the data from the reference to the given string, because that's what it's designed to do. A function named `calc_sha1()` might just examine the data to calculate a checksum, and never copy it. A string-searching function might only look at part of the data, and stop after finding the string it looks for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`String` and `str` are stored as contiguous arrays of UTF-8 bytes.

```
String "foo"                         &str "bar"
[ len: 3 | data:┐ ]                  [ len: 3 | data:┐ ]
                │                                    │
                v                                    v
                [ f | o | o ]   [ more memory... ]   [ b | a | r ]
```

When you do `s1.push_str(&s2[..])`, the bytes of `s2` are copied to the end of the memory owned by `s1` (possibly reallocating to make more room), leaving `s2` as it is.

```
              ┌────────────────────┐
              v                    │
[ f | o | o | b | a | r ]        [ b | a | r ]
```

The fact that the underlying bytes must be contiguous means there's no way to perform a non-copying append operation with Rust's `String`/`&str` types. Such an operation would require a string type implemented as, for instance, a linked list of string chunks rather than a single contiguous array.

Comment: "*a linked list of string chunks*"... or a `Vec<&str>`.

Comment: or a [rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29)